# Rx-based tree structure with UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I want to implement a tree structure by using RxCocoa & RxSwift in a `UITableView` something like

```
 Item1
     child1
          child1.1
          child1.2             
     child2
 Item2
 Item3
     child1
     child2
          child2.1
          child2.2
          child2.3
```

I tried with ***RxDataSource***.
**RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource** worked when the depth is 1.

Is there anyway to make it infinitely recursive?

Comment: Don't know rx but that structure is not too difficult to DIY. Just add a pointer to parent for each node?

Comment: OPer, please post the salient portion of your source code for RxDataSource.  Please post the salient portion of your source code for RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource.  Please explain in detail what you seek by “make it infinitely recursive” such as arbitrarily deep known at run-time instead of at engineering-time.  (Or do you simply mean arbitrarily deep at engineering-time when writing the source code?)

Comment: Making an RxSwift data source able to handle levels is no different than making any other UITableViewDataSource able to handle levels. How would you do this without using Rx?